# jquery heirarchial accordion tree

Tags: jquery, treeview, accordion

I need a suggestion regarding how I can make an accordion tree hierarchical. There are many plugins available, but they do not fit my requirement.

My requirement is as follows: Suppose I click on my child node, then that should become the parent node for the rest of its child elements, and if I click on it again then it should display its child's parent element.

I want to start by using jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding, you should be able to nest the JqueryUI accordions. If you want to make it appear as a tree, you can change the JQueryUI css.

See here:
http://jsbin.com/adole3/edit

However, note that with an accordion, only one section of the accordion can be open at a time. If you want several sections to be open at once, view the code under the note on this page:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Here is an implementation (no styles) from the above:
http://jsbin.com/enika3/2/edit

Comment: heyy thank u very much ur tutorial is helpfull for me thanks.